# Coolant Reservoir: Why doesn't air pressure escape through the overflow hose?

Tags: coolant, malibu, coolant-reservoir, air

**Background:**

I am in the process of troubleshooting an overheating/coolant problem with my 2005 Chevy Malibu. For what it's worth, I suspect there is air in the coolant lines which is delaying/preventing the engine from cooling properly (although I'm not a car guy, so this could very well be incorrect).

**Observation:**

I opened the cap of the coolant reservoir today (the last time the car ran was 24 hours ago).

Quite a bit of air pressure hissed/escaped out of the reservoir when I removed the cap.

**Question:**

I didn't expect there to be air pressure in the reservoir. There is clearly an overflow hose on the reservoir, so why didn't the air escape through the overflow hose beforehand? Why did the air only escape when I removed the cap?

(I can confirm that the overflow hose is not blocked because coolant flows through it.)

---

*I'm asking for curiosity's sake. And I suppose there is a chance this is related to the overheating/coolant issues that I've been troubleshooting.*

Comment: When you open the pressure cap you should not get getting air.  The space under pressure should not contain air at all but should be full of coolant.

Comment: The OP removed the cap on the reservoir, not the radiator. I'm guessing the overflow in the reservoir might be plugged. As far as overheating goes, I have seen head gasket leaks that put hot exhaust gases into the coolant. The symptom: the engine overheats within minutes of starting, much like an espresso machine.